# What is the maximum difference between these two functions?

Tags: number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

Supposed the function $f(n)$ is defined as follows:

For values of $n$ less than or equal to $121$

$$f(n)=
\begin{cases}
    0 ,& \text{if } n < 121\\
    1 ,& \text{if } n = 121\\
\end{cases}$$

For values of $n$ greater than $121$

$$f(n+1)= 
\begin{cases}
    f(n) ,& \text{if $n+1$ is not evenly divisible by 11}\\
    f(n) ,& \text{if  $n+1$ is evenly divisible by 2,3,5,7}\\
    f(n)+ 1 ,& \text{if  $n+1$ is evenly divisible by 11 but not 2,3,5 or 7}\\
\end{cases}$$
Basically, $f(n)$ increments when a value of $n$ is encountered that is evenly divsible by 11 and no lower prime number.

Also, let's suppose the function $g(n)$ is defined as follows:

$$g(n) = (n/2)(2/3)(4/5)(6/7)(1/11)$$

What is the maximum difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for any natural number $n$?

How do you calculate this difference?

Comment: what has been tried ?

Answer (score 0):

First note that for $n<11$ the maximum difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ is at $n=10$, where
$$|f(10)-g(10)|=\frac{16}{77}.$$
For $n\geq11$ the function $f$ satisfies
$$f(n+1)=\begin{cases}
    f(n)+1 & \text{ if }\gcd(2310,n+1)=11\\
    f(n)   & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$
For every $n\in\Bbb{N}$ the number of integers $m$ with $n\leq m<n+2310$ and $\gcd(2310,m)=11$ is precisely 
$$\varphi(\tfrac{2310}{11})=\varphi(2\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7)=\varphi(2)\varphi(3)\varphi(5)\varphi(7)=1\cdot2\cdot4\cdot6=48,$$
which shows that $f(n+2310)=f(n)+48$ for all $n\geq11$. On the other hand
$$g(n)=\frac n2\frac23\frac45\frac67\frac{1}{11}=\frac{48}{2310}n,$$
which shows that also $g(n+2310)=g(n)+48$ for all $n\geq11$. This shows that the maximum difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ is achieved with $11\leq n<2321$.

So to find the maximum difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for $n\in\Bbb{N}$, it suffices to find the maximum difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for $11\leq n<2321$, and to check that this does not exceed the maximum difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ for $n<11$. A quick check shows that the maximum is
$$\frac{828}{385}=g(1066)-f(1066).$$
**Edit:** As noted in the comments, this is not the maximum. A second check, this time with a computer, shows that the maximum is at $n=120$, where
$$|f(120)-g(120)|=|0-120\cdot\tfrac{48}{2310}|=\frac{192}{77}\approx2.4935.$$

Comment: g(2429) = (2429/2)*(2/3)*(4/5)*(6/7)*(1/11) = 50.4727 and 

f(2429) = 48.

So the difference between |g(2429) - f(2429)| = 2.4727 which is greater than 828/385.

Comment: The maximum difference between f(n) and g(n) occurs between 121 < n < 2431

Comment: A second check, this time with a computer, shows that the maximum is at $n=120$ with
$$|f(n)-g(n)|=|0-120\cdot\tfrac{48}{2310}|=\frac{192}{77}\approx2.4935.$$